# Доменная сеть с виртуальными машинами hyper-V

Tags: сервер, сеть, виртуальная-машина, hyper-v

Требуется создать несколько виртуальных машин (Ubuntu,Ubuntu server и Centos) доступ к ним через суб домены(6 суб доменов будет) , что бы был, хостовая ОС стоит Windows server 2022 и гипервизор Hyper-V.
Можете пошагово написать шаги для реализации задумки?
С созданием машин проблем нет, проблемы возникают с этапом сети, не понимаю что делать и в каком порядке. Есть готовые домен.ру и суб.домены.ру

Comment: доступ через домены из вне имеется ввиду? а ip один или разные?

Comment: а зачем тут AD?

Comment: @4per да, доступ нужен с любого компьютера вне локальной сети.AD видимо не при чем как я уже понял, если нужно настроить из вне?

Comment: мне кажется AD не нужна, но я далеко не уверен. А что с IP?

Comment: @4per ip динамичный, но через роутер можно сделать статичный.

Comment: Мне бы понять цепочку, я с радостью буду гуглить, но пока я не понимаю даже, с чего начать.

Comment: внешний ip один на всех или на каждого свой?

Comment: ещё важно какие порты на серверах вас интересуют

Comment: @4per внешний ip вроде один, в hyper-v создан виртуальный адаптер. Порты не знаю, 80 вроде обычно прокидывается же для субдоменов?

Comment: если по порту\ip нельзя идентифицировать куда пришёл запрос, нужен балансировщик способный определить на какой домен пришёл запрос. Вроде nginx это может.

Comment: @4per А nginx на windows можно поставить? Я читал, что лучше Apache для windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создать в Диспетчере виртуальных коммуникаторов виртуальный коммуникатор с типом Внешняя сеть;
2. Создать машину (со статическим mac, и закрепить его в DNS или роутере).
3. Пункт 2 повторить для каждой виртуальной машины.

Comment: Виртуальный коммуникатор создан, но настройки ip в нём стоят "автоматические".
Машина есть на Ubuntu, завтра закреплю.
А как сделать так, что бы я мог заходить на нужную виртуалку через 1.domen.ru/2.domen.ru?

Comment: Непонятно, что значит заходить на виртуалку через домен. Обычно при установке Ubuntu/Centos сразу открывают 22 порт и его (их) пробрасывают в роутере. У вас будет 3 порта наружу смотреть (например 22, 222 и 2222 на 22-е в машинах)

Comment: Ну это значит захожу я например на суб.домен.ру и у меня открывается например Ubuntu, через логин и пароль. Через 80 порт как всё это сделать?

Comment: Зачем через 80?

Comment: @4per а через какой? Я так понимаю у меня основная проблема сейчас это правильно настроить DNS сервер, что бы публичный доступ был к под домену.

Comment: Делайте порт форвардинг как написал автор ответа, берите разные порты. Я думал вам нужен доступ по http, раз вы говорили про 80 порт

Comment: ТС не понимает чем отличаются 80 и 22 порты. Если у вас уже настроены сайты (сервисы) на этих ВМ, то открывайте 80, 8080, 8088 на 80-е машин. И подумайте сразу над https. А если ещё ничего не настроено, то 22 порты открывают. Dns тут не при чём

Comment: @DmitriiA Проблема в том, что сам поддомен пингуется только внутри сети по внутреннему ip ВМ, вне сети не пингуется. Но в браузере страница не открывается, порты открыты, возможно я что то на ВМ недонастроил, там Ubuntu чистая стоит, поставил apache2, по гайду настроил, но ничего это не изменило.

Answer (score 0):

Пробросил порты "80" для каждой VM и через Apache2 прописал ip и адрес домена, всё работает.